# SP2010: Simply need to figure out why my SPServices UpdatePermissions call reports success but permissions remain unchanged

Tags: javascript, permissions, spservices

Examples of how to use this UpdatePermissions or AddPermission call in JavaScript *alone* would be awesome and appreciated, but of course any clues or information with regards to my main question would be a huge help.

**Relevant Background Information**

I have a sharepoint site with a doc library, with a webpart that points to a JavaScript.

Said script creates a directory in a library in a subsite.

Once this directory appears in the library, a workflow is triggered that removes all the inherited groups.

I then call a method that is supposed to then grant permissions to a given group on the site, using the UpdatePermissions SPService call. It looks like this:

```
function editPermissions() {
    function doIt() {
        $().SPServices({
            operation: 'AddPermission',
            objectType: 'Web',
            objectName: 'https://site.mysite.me.com/sites/SpecialProject/Sub_Site/DocLibrary/Name Of the Folder I Just Made',
            permissionIdentifier: 'Group Name Here as It Appears on the Site',
            permissionType: 'group',
            permissionMask: 1012866047,
            debug: true,
            completefunc: function(xData, Status) {
                xmlText = Status +"\n" + xData.responseText;
            }
        });
    }

    function display() {
        xmlText = xmlText.replace(/</g, "&#60;\n");
        xmlText = xmlText.replace(/>/g, "&#62;\n");
        console.log(xmlText);

        $( "p" ).append("<br> " + xmlText);
    } 

    setTimeout(doIt, 2000);
    setTimeout(display, 3000);
}
```

The idea of this script is to add back in, of the groups that were removed by the SPD workflow, the one group that is supposed to have access.

Since there are no real good detailed examples out there for this call, I'm not sure if I'm using the correct syntax.

However the the script reports that it is successful, which would seem to suggest that my syntax is at least somewhat kosher.

**The Problem**

So the main problem is that when I click manage permissions for this folder on the GUI of my site the group that was to be added does not appear as one of the groups that are supposed to have permissions, even though the call is reported to have been run successfully.

Any ideas, comments clues, links, examples would be appreciated anything at all really would be great.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Who is supposed to be executing this script? It is only going to allow someone to add the group to the permissions if they have the permissions to do so (Design or Full Control) on the object. For users who do not have access, it would not do anything.